# jQuery dropdown with nested tables

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple levels of data set up in nested tables. I want it to drill down into each level. How should I accomplish this? This jQuery has been working for my nested `ul` and `li` items on other pages, it doesn't seem to work for the nested tables though. Any suggestions?

HTML :

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>head1</th>
      <th>head2</th>
      <th>head3</th>
   </tr>
   <tr class="dropClick">
      <td>8/2/2013</td>
      <td>$960.00</td>
      <td>$48.14</td>
      <table class="dropDown">
         <tr class="dropClick">
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>$960.00</td>
            <table class="dropDown">
               <tr>
                  <td>data</td>
                  <td>data</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>data</td>
                  <td>data</td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </tr>
         <!--end dropClick-->
         <tr class="dropClick">
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>$72.56</td>
            <table class="dropDown">
               <tr>
                  <td>data</td>
                  <td>data</td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                  <td>data</td>
                  <td>data</td>
               </tr>
            </table>
         </tr>
         <!--end dropClick-->
         <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>$873.50</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>$48.14</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </tr>
   <!--end dropClick-->
</table>
```

Script :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dropDown").hide();

    $(".dropClick").click(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.find(".dropDown").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Invalid HTML does not help

Answer (score 0):

I would not have nested tables with same class name. Make sure that the class names are different if they are nested.

Comment: so you would just create a new jQuery statement for each class then?

Comment: Ho many rows do you have in your top level table? If the tables or rows are in the same level then there are no issues in having the same class name. Once they are nested and 2 DOM elements have the same class names and you are using jquery to toggle visibility it becomes a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you MIGHT mean this

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/RL2AP/)

```
$(function () {
    $(".dropDown").hide();
    $(".dropClick").on("click",function () {
        var $nextDrop = $(this).parent().find(".dropDown").first();
        $nextDrop.slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

using corrected html with the dropdown class on the row that contains the drop down table

Comment: This is close. However, I am trying to make the tables drill down in a mobile app. So I want each drop down to take up the width of the screen. Using your HTML it seems like the child tables are stuck in the parent column. I can't seem to get them to take up the full screen width in the CSS, any suggestions?

Comment: Would I be able to keep each drop down on the same screen then, or would it navigate to the next page displaying the drilled down info?

Comment: Make each a div with data-role page http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/docs-pages.html